# Definition of differentiability and derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I am recently learning the Rigorous definition of the derivative so now I come across a problem here is the definition of derivative and definition of differentiability

> A real function $f$ is said to be differentiable at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f$ is defined on some open interval $I$ containing $a$ and
> $$f^{\prime}(a) :=\lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
> exists. In this case $f^{\prime}(a)$ is called the derivative of $f$ at $a$

and

> Let $I$ be an interval. A function $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is said to be differentiable on $I$ if and only if$$f^{\prime}(a) :=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ exists and is finite for every $a \in I $

I feel first definition also can be used for differentiability

Let $I$ be an interval. A function $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is said to be differentiable on $I$ if and only if $$f^{\prime}(x) :=\lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ exists and is finite for every $x \in I $

My problem is what is the difference between these two? Why there is two formula for one thing?

Comment: in the case where $I$ is open, the two definitions are equivalent for defining differentiability for $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @CSquared when $I$ is closed fisr one is wrong?

Comment: not wrong, but it is just not well defined with the first definition. in John Hughes' answer, the function $f$ which he defines is a good example. The left sided limit is not defined at $x=0$, so the first definition does not define a derivative there.

Comment: @CSquared Got it but what is better definition?

Comment: @CSquared Thank you very much, helpful

Comment: my apologies, one definition is not more general than the other, they are essentially the same, but you just have to be careful at endpoints of intervals. The limits may not exist there using the given definitions. A "better" or more inclusive definition would be including one sided limits at endpoints for defining derivatives at endpoints of closed intervals

Comment: @CSquared John Hughes's answer is same thank you

Comment: @CSquared if $(0,1)$,$f$ differentiable according the 1st definition  since $0,1$ is not in domain is it correct?

Comment: yes that’s right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two definitions because you're defining two different things:

1. $f$ is differentiable at the point $x$.
2. $f$ is differentiable on the interval $I$.

If I were writing the text, I'd define the first one, and then say that $f$ is differentiable on $I$ if for every point $b \in I$, $f$ is differentiable at $b$. I don't know why your author didn't do this. One peculiarity (which may depend on how the author defined limits) is that it's possible (in the given definition) for the function to be differentiable on a closed interval $I$ without being differentiable at the endpoints. Why? Because maybe there's no open interval around the endpoint that's entirely contained in the domain of $f$. [If *having* such an interval is an essential part of the author's definition of limit, then it should probably have been omitted from the definition of derivative.]

As an example, consider the function
$$
f:[0, 1] \to [0, 1] : x \mapsto x.
$$
This happens to take on the same values as $$
g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto x
$$
at every point $x$ of the unit interval, but $f$ is **undefined** outside that unit interval nonetheless.

As an example of this subtle distinction:

For this function, the limit in the second definition is well-defined** at $x = 0$, for instance, but the function is not differentiable at $x = 0$ (according to the first definition) because $f$ is not defined on any open interval containing $x = 0$.

**at least, it's well-defined if the definition of "limit" is the one I'm thinking of; it may be that your author uses something different.

NB: Most folks would require "and is finite" as part of the definition of differentiability as well; it's not clear why your author omitted that.

Comment: thank you. can you please state one such a interval(example)

Comment: @Akalanka some authors will "loosen" the definition of differentiability by accepting one sided limits in examples like the ones given above. But, with the first definition, the function $f$ is not differentiable on $[0,1]$ since it is not differentiable at $0$ or $1$. It is however, differentiable on $(0,1)$. can you see why?

Answer (score 1):

Replace $h$ with $x-a$ in the first definition to see that the two limit definitions of the derivative are equivalent.

One of your definitions is for differentiability at a point and the other for differentiability on an interval.

Comment: But why there is two definitions